# Does Pandas Interpolate function place a restriction on the index?

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I was expecting pandas interpolate "values" to be able to handle arbitrary indexes, but perhaps not. Consider

```
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   dm = pd.DataFrame(index=[0, 4, 3, 2],data={"Col1":[1,2,np.NaN,6]})
   print(dm)

   print ("Expecting: ", 2+(3-4)/(2-4)*(6-2))
   dm = dm.interpolate(method='values')
   print(dm)
```

but no... I get the expected answer only if the index values are in increasing order and the unknown value is in between. Is there a flag that I can add to the interpolate function?

Answer (score 0):

You can interpolate sorted by index `pd.Series`.

```py
dm["Col1"] = dm["Col1"].sort_index().interpolate(method='values')
>>> dm
   Col1
0   1.0
4   2.0
3   4.0
2   6.0
```

The trick is to keep the original index in tact, while sorting for interpolation. Cause dataframe on the left side will get the proper values of a dataframe on the right, accordingly to its index and regardless of actual order.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is, say, x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7 and y1,y2,NaN,y4,NaN,NaN,y7

Comment: Thanks, Grzegorz, but the problem is, say, x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7 and y1,y2,NaN,y4,NaN,NaN,y7  then I want the first NaN to be interpolated between (x2,y2) and (x4,y4) and the second set of NaN's to be interpolated between (x4,y4) and (x7,y7). If you sort the xi's then it'd be wrong. What I coded tonight was to look for the next batch of NaN's in a while-loop and then for each batch, I call scipy interp1d with assume_sorted=False,fill_value='extrapolate'. It's ugly, but will do for now.

Comment: Gotcha, but still - you just need to put some custom sorting function (maybe using ```pd.Series.sort_values()``` instead) to ensure chronology.